# getty start from command line?

Tags: getty

I have a line in my inittab like the following:

```
# Put a getty on the serial port
ttyS0::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
```

If I try to perform a similar operation from an [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) session command line (this time towards a usb-serial adapter I have):

```
/sbin/getty -L ttyUSB0 115200 vt100
```

I receive the following response:

```
getty: setsid: Operation not permitted
```

Is i possible to launch the [getty](/questions/tagged/getty) process from my [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) session and have a serial [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal) be presented on the usb-serial adapter? Why does this have to occur in inittab?

Comment: Apparently [this](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2012-August/078268.html) error has something do with the fact that I am using busybox, though I am still not sure how to resolve the problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved that problem running :

```
su root -c "getty /dev/ttyXX"
```

I am running busybox 1.23.1 on an ARM platform.

Comment: From what I can gather, I believe my system has some sort of problem. I was able to perform the command on other systems using the same adapters/cables and the getty works just fine.

Comment: For reference, I had to add the force local line parameter to my command:  `su root -c "getty -L 115200 ttyUSB0"`

Comment: I'm using BusyBox v1.31.1 and running as root. I get the same error as the OP. Any suggestions on how to diagnose this further?