# Ubuntu reboots at startup as default runlevel is set to 6

Tags: ubuntu, runlevel

Someone has changed my default runlevel to 6 so whenever I start Ubuntu it reboots..

Can anyone help me by suggesting some solution how to change my default runlevel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu has recovery shell option, which is accessible through grub menu's Advanced Options for Ubuntu. Remember to remount system with `mount / -o rw,remount` in order to allow changes to the system.

Alternatively, you can get to the grub menu, highlight `Ubuntu`, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the entry. Add `init=/bin/bash`, change default runlevel, reboot. [Related link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34462/85039)

There's also [liveCD/ liveUSB recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) option.

Consult the [ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto#How_do_I_change_the_default_runlevel.3F) for changing runlevels as well as booting to single user mode

Answer (score 1):

Boot in single user mode (probably edit the boot command, adding a "1" at the end), and once the system is running, change the default runlevel back.