# Are all kernel argument really used by the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

[Why does Linux allow ‘init=/bin/bash’?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34462/why-does-linux-allow-init-bin-bash)

I read this, answers are saying it's KERNEL running this init program.

Then I started to wonder, Linux usually comes with a initramfs, which will eventually mount and pivot_root to real root filesystem.  So what does this `init` argument mean? The path in the initramfs? Or like I guessed, it's not read by the kernel but by init of initramfs to exec the real init.

Also, the `root=UUID=xxxx` argument, is that really read by kernel  or just by init of initramfs to find the real root filesystem?

It seems like I can pass any argument I want as kernel arguments, so are they all read by the kernel or at least some of them are only meaningful to userspace programs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Parameters passed on the kernel command line don’t have to be meaningful for the kernel: [the kernel parameters documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) says

> The kernel parses parameters from the kernel command line up to “--”; if it doesn’t recognize a parameter and it doesn’t contain a ‘.’, the parameter gets passed to init: parameters with ‘=’ go into init’s environment, others are passed as command line arguments to init. Everything after “--” is passed as an argument to init.

This doesn’t apply to `init` and `root` which really are kernel parameters, and are handled by the kernel. They can also be acted upon by user-space, since they appear in `/proc/cmdline`. (Thus for example systemd takes the `quiet` kernel parameter into account to reduce its output.)

When the kernel is booted with an initramfs, the `root` parameter isn’t *used* by the kernel directly, and the `init` parameter is only used if `rdinit` fails. `init` startup is handled in [`kernel_init`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.14/source/init/main.c#L1064), which works as follows:

- if there’s a “ramdisk execute command” (either the value given to `rdinit` on the kernel command line, or `/init`) which is accessible, the kernel attempts to run that;
- if that fails, and there’s an “execute command” (the value given to `init` on the kernel command line), the kernel attempts to run that, and panics if it can’t;
- as a last resort, the kernel tries to run `/sbin/init`, `/etc/init`, `/bin/init`, and `/bin/sh`; if none of those can be run, it [panics](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/init.html).

When there’s an initramfs, all of this happens there, and the target volume isn’t mounted by the kernel. What happens *after* the kernel runs the first `init` program (typically, the `/init` script in the initramfs) is up to the program, not the kernel. Arguments which aren’t passed to `init` are still available in `/proc/cmdline` if the `/proc` file system is mounted.

Comment: Also a little curious, what if init-in-the-initramfs is a set-uid-non-root file? A file without executable bit? Will it be run as root anyway? What if it's broken ELF or can't find `ld-linux.so` ELF or recursion-too-deep script or anything just can't be execve?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the kernel doesn't load the program specified in "init=" from the initramfs. It an initramfs is in use then it seems to run as normal before the user-specified init program is run (not sure if it's the kernel that does this or code in the initramfs).

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 To specify an alternate program instead of `/init` when booting from a ramdisk, you can use the `rdinit=/path/to` boot parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Passing custom kernel arguments is one way to customize a system during a KickStart install, for example a PXE server could set:

```
linuxefi /c7/vmlinuz ks=http://.../ks/c7 lab ksdevice=eth0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0
```

where `lab` is then used in the KickStart configuration to do different things than for other system builds:

```
%pre
...
case " $(cat /proc/cmdline)" in
   ...
   *\ lab*)
      filesystems_lab
      ;;
   *)
      filesystems_common
      ;;
...
```

Here to setup a different filesystem layout than used on other system types. Hopefully different labels are used for local customizations than are used by the kernel, given the single namespace involved.