# Debian 11: Recovery Mode from grub menu doesn't work because root user is locked, how to enable Recovery Mode?

Tags: debian, grub

Context: Ubuntu user considering moving to Debian so trying some test installs.

In Ubuntu you could choose the advanced options from the grub menu, select recovery mode, and if `friendly-recovery` was installed, enable networking and drop to a root shell to fix things.

I just tried this in my test Debian install, and it didn't work because "the root user is locked". I thought the root user was locked in Ubuntu as well, but apparently this is something more restrictive.

How can I get recovery mode to work in Debian 11?

Comment: Did you install Debian without a root password?

Comment: Debian doesn't ask for root password during install, only user pwd. Does this help? https://www.linuxtechi.com/boot-debian-rescue-emergency-mode/

Comment: @Peregrino69 thanks, that looks promising. Will try it.

Comment: @Peregrino69
 I recently installed another Debian instance -- it will ask for a root password (which can be skipped, and will lock it). It's Ubuntu that doesn't ask and locks it by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can append [`rw init=/bin/bash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34462/why-does-linux-allow-init-bin-bash) to your kernel boot parameters or boot from the Debian USB installer in "Rescue Mode" (Advanced options->Rescue mode) and drop to a root shell with network even if the root account is locked. You need to know the partition of your root filesystem.

I can confirm that `friendly-recovery` doesn't work with a locked root account, I get

```
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press enter to continue
```

If the account is not locked, you still need to enter the password.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comment from [Jaromanda X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/401568/jaromanda-x), it appears that the easiest way to enable `friendly-recovery` is to set a root password with `sudo passwd root`.

This doesn't seem to be quite the way Ubuntu does it - when I drop to a root shell in `friendly-recovery` in Ubuntu, it does not prompt you for a password, whereas Debian does - so I am still looking into it, but this is acceptable for now.

I would still eagerly receive answers on what the difference with the Ubuntu implementation is.